# Media 'external video' requests iframe over http instead of https, leading to mixed content errors and blocked video

Tags: 9, media

I have a drupal 9 site where I use the media library. I've created a media type with source "External video", allowing youtube videos. As far as I can see this uses oEmbed.

I've added a media reference field for this type in a contenttype and created content. However, when I try to view the page the video won't show and I have a mixed content warning in the console of the browser.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame
 'http://xxx/media/oembed/?url=https%3A//youtu.be/someIDHERE&max_width=890&max_height=560&hash=0nPSIkGE5CqEuiNAmZ1wdR1rXpwkg5r3GkoTyeZaR-g'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I've set all correct settings for reverse proxy in settings.php, and the base url in the settings reflects this by showing https, but somehow this particular part of Drupal insists on using http, rather than https.

How can I make sure it requests this video frame using https?

Comment: What is your setting for I-Frame domain in `/admin/config/media/media-settings`?

Comment: Haven't added anything there, it's still empty.